# In Vue 3, how do I change the key without rerendering the object

Tags: vuejs3, vue-sfc

I've got a list of object that are sorted alphabetically.

```js
   <li class="list-item" v-for="item in sortedItems" :key="item.id">
     {{ item.name }} (id = {{ item.id }})
   </li>
```

When I create a new object the `item.id` will be `0`, because I don't know what id the item will get in the database.

After saving the new new object to the database, I want to update the `item.id`.
My problem is that the key is set to the id `:key="item.id"`, so that the key will change with the id. **Changing the key will usually force a rerender and I don't want a rerender** (because I don't want some animations to trigger).

My question is: Can you somehow change the key of an object such that Vue thinks it is still the same object?

A reproduction of my problem can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-wind-6w2lcz?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: You could set your key to a different field like a "frontend only" id, separate from your database id.  https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-wind-th6ck2?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: That is actually a really good idea!

Comment: item.name as the key